# Passing a filename from Java to R using Rjava eclipse plugin

Tags: java, r

I have a issue in passing a String filename from a program in Java to a R program .

This are the R statement i want to run from my Java Program . the filename parameter should come from java

```
library(readr)
  ORE_Data <- read_csv(filename)
  data_boxplot<-boxplot(ORE_Data)
  result<-data_boxplot$out
  return(result)
```

my java program is as follows

```
String _file = "D:\\Yogesh\\ORE_Data.csv";
         re.eval("library(readr)",true);
         //re.assign("_file",_file);- Have tried this Does not work
         // re.eval("a<-'D:\\Yogesh\\ORE_Data.csv'"); - Have tried this Does //not work
         re.eval("ORE_Data<-read_csv(a)",true);
         re.eval("data_boxplot<-boxplot(ORE_Data)",true);
         REXP rExpression = re.eval("data_boxplot$out",true);
         System.out.println(rExpression3);
```

Note that it works if i pass the hardcoded values as 
re.eval("a<-c(2,3,2,2,1,1,21);
but somehow does not work when i am passing the value as a string .

Does anyone have a clue here . Any help is appreciated